# How to fix random string names issue while uploading zip files in Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload, google-colaboratory, drive

Recently, I had to transfer some large files to Google Drive, and I considered using Google Colab for the task. I wrote a simple Python code for the process. However, while moving the files, I encountered an issue with uploading zip files. Although the files were successfully uploaded, the zip files were given random string names instead of their actual file names. what should I do to fix this issue?

This is the code:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
from google.colab import drive
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse, unquote

drive.mount('/content/drive')

download_link = input("Enter the download link: ")

destination_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/downloads/'

if not os.path.exists(destination_folder):
    os.makedirs(destination_folder)

response = requests.head(download_link, allow_redirects=True)
file_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))
progress_bar = tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True)

parsed_url = urlparse(download_link)
file_name = unquote(parsed_url.path.split('/')[-1])

response = requests.get(download_link, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()

file_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)
with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
        if chunk:
            file.write(chunk)
            progress_bar.update(len(chunk))

progress_bar.close()

print(f"File '{file_name}' uploaded successfully to '{destination_folder}'.")
```

I used a torrent to test this and extract the media contents. In the torrents, I used Seedr to extract the files. When downloading the files using a download manager in the usual way, the files are downloaded with their original zip names, for example, "Ocean 4K video Test". However, when uploading the files to Google Drive using code, they are uploaded with random string names like "e07316f5f8b084edcfd55c6d5d25038dd7ed99acece70e525506179407fd0522.zip".